# How to search mysql databse using an array via php/ajax?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I found quite a few similar questions asked but none of them seem to be close to what I am trying to do.

**Question:**

I have a php code that searches mysql database and returns data based on the users location (lat/long). and it prints the data as a JSON. (this works fine and as it should).

The code looks like this:

```
$latitude2 = floatval($_GET['latitude']); //no default
$longitude2 = floatval($_GET['longitude']); //no default

   $sql ="SELECT b.*
   FROM businesses b 
  ORDER
     BY -- great circle distance calculation
        ( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS('" . $latitude2. "') )
                     * COS( RADIANS( b.lat ) )
                     * COS( RADIANS( b.lon ) 
                            - RADIANS('" . $longitude2 . "') 
                          )
                     + SIN( RADIANS('" . $latitude2 . "') )
                     * SIN( RADIANS( b.lat ) ) 
                 ) 
        ) ASC  LIMIT 4";
```

Now, I need to add one more search parameter to the above query. This parameter is an array which is created by checked checkboxes and it looks like this:

```
 [{"title":"Toys"},{"title":"Restaurants"},{"title":"Hotel"},{"title":"Pets"},{"title":"Accounting"}]
```

So, I send this extra parameter to my PHP page like all other parameters via AJAX and I get the array in my php like so:

```
$filters = $_GET['filters'];
```

But I don't know how I can add this extra parameter to my current query so my php returns data based on the value in that array.

I tried something like this which doesn't work:

```
$latitude2 = floatval($_GET['latitude']); //no default
$longitude2 = floatval($_GET['longitude']); //no default
$filters = $_GET['filters'];


   $sql ="SELECT b.*
   FROM businesses b 
  ORDER
     BY -- great circle distance calculation
        ( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS('" . $latitude2. "') )
                     * COS( RADIANS( b.lat ) )
                     * COS( RADIANS( b.lon ) 
                            - RADIANS('" . $longitude2 . "') 
                          )
                     + SIN( RADIANS('" . $latitude2 . "') )
                     * SIN( RADIANS( b.lat ) ) 
                 ) 
        ) ASC WHERE categories='$filters' LIMIT 4";
```

This `WHERE categories='$filters'` is wrong.

Could someone please advice on this issue?

**EDIT:**

I tried it every which way to no avail. I even tried it like so and still didn't get any results back from the database:

```
   $sql ="SELECT b.*
   FROM businesses b 
  ORDER
     BY -- great circle distance calculation
        ( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS('" . $latitude2. "') )
                     * COS( RADIANS( b.lat ) )
                     * COS( RADIANS( b.lon ) 
                            - RADIANS('" . $longitude2 . "') 
                          )
                     + SIN( RADIANS('" . $latitude2 . "') )
                     * SIN( RADIANS( b.lat ) ) 
                 ) 
        ) ASC WHERE FIND_IN_SET(b.categories, 'Toys, Restaurants, Hotel') LIMIT 4";
```

Comment: Does your MySQL categories column contain single value or multiple values?

Comment: @NadirLatif, Single values. example: one has Restaurants and one has Hotel and so on and so forth.

Comment: @Dharman, this is not my code. its a code that I am working on written by someone else. might switch to PS in the future.

Answer (score 2):

The filters variable contains a json string. You need to convert it to Php array using [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

After that get the values of each title. Next use the MySQL function [FIND_IN_SET](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_find_in_set.asp). For example:

```
where FIND_IN_SET(categories, 'category1,category2,category3') >0
```

Comment: can I do `$filters = json_decode($_GET['filters']);` and then `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(categories, '$filters')` ?

Comment: Well use json_decode($_GET['filters'], true). It will return an array. This array contains arrays in the format "title" => "some title". So you need to use a for loop to get the value of title. Put each title in an array. Next convert this array to string using $string = implode(",", $array). You can use this string in the SQL query. For example: where FIND_IN_SET(categories, $string)

Answer (score 1):

It could be good to simply run such a query to see what happens - probably, you would have received an error message telling you that the `WHERE` clause should occur **before** the `ORDER BY`

Comment: but the problem is that I am not doing anything with the array that I get in my php. I don't think the whole query is right because php cannot search mysql database like this: `WHERE categories='[{"title":"Toys"},{"title":"Restaurants"},{"title":"Hotel"},{"title":"Pets"},{"title":"Accounting"}]'`

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that, but fixing your query might be a good start. And if you think that inserting the string directly is wrong, what keeps you from changing it such that it is no longer wrong? I don't have a clue about your database structure

Comment: what I meant is the issue is not by positioning the WHERE clause as you suggested.

Comment: but you are right... that is one of the issues. still not returning anything though!

Comment: Now, everything works. a mixture of your suggestion and @Nadir Latif, I managed to make it work.

Answer (score -1):

`WHERE IN` is what you need
`WHERE id IN ('".$array."')");`

Let's try

Comment: Can you explain that further? `$array` does not occur in the code shared by James

Comment: Well using IN is a good option. But it needs to be `WHERE categories IN ('category1,category2,category3'), since we are checking for categories and not id. See: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/in-function.php. Also the arguments to IN needs to be list of categories in string format